# Java Question mark inside println()

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that solves equations, i want the answer to be displayed in the right way, if the number is negative, to display -x and not +-x,
for example,
Eq1: 4x-3 and not 4x+-3, but when it is positive to display 4x+3. I can't use the plus sign inside the quotations.
I wanted to use the ? : operator. 
I tried something like this

```
System.out.println("Eq1: "+ ((a11>0) ? (+ "+" + (int)a11) : + (int)a11) +"*x1+");
```

This line is supposed to print the negative number (i.e. it will be -2*x1) and if it's positive it should display the + sign and add the number, but it gives me an error around the + "+" +

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: i don't really understand what you want to do, but the same code without syntax error: System.out.println("Eq1: "+ ((a11>0) ? ("+" + (int)a11) : + (int)a11) +"*x1+");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make the variable always positive, like so

```
"Eq1: " + (a11 >= 0 ? " + " + (int)a11 : " - " + (int)(-a11)) + " * x1 +"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried System.out.printf()? Here's a link.[printf](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang/System.out.printf.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the string

```
String.format("Ed1: %+d x %+d", v1,v2);
```

Where

`%+d` - is the formatting expression, that stands for "hire display a number with sign"

v1 and v2 are number values.

Exection example

```
 v1  v2  result
  1  1   Ed1: +1 x +1
  2  0   Ed1: +2 x +0
  3 -2   Ed1: +1 x -2
 -3  2   Ed1: -3 x +2
 -2 -1   Ed1: -2 x -1
 -1 -4   Ed1: -1 x -4
```

[More](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the ternary operator is already less readable than a simple if/else statement. But if it's used to concatenate (using the + operator) the symbol "+", it becomes really really unreadable.

How about this:

```
String s = Integer.toString(a11);
if (a11 > 0) {
    s = "+" + s;
}
System.out.println("Eq1: 4x" + s);
```

Answer (score -1):

i don't really understand what you want to do, but try this:

```
 System.out.println("Eq1: "+ ((a11>0) ? ("+" + (int)a11) : + (int)a11) +"*x1+");
```

it's the same code as yours, but without the syntax error.

Comment: Use comments for comments, answers for answers.

Comment: @Vash: this is an answer. it does exactly what he/she wants.